# Symfony cloning entity persist old entity

Tags: symfony

I've a form with two submit buttons, "Save and overwrite" and "Save as copy".

So here is the problem, when I'm creating the copy with the next code, the old entity is still being updated:

```
public function EditAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $auth_checker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');
    $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();

    // Get our user from that token
    $user = $token->getUser();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $checklist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Checklist')->find($id);


    if (!$checklist) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Checklist not found... ' . $id);
    }

    $originalGroups = new ArrayCollection();
    $originalTasks = new ArrayCollection();
    $originalCorrectives = new ArrayCollection();

    /** @var ChecklistGroup $group */
    foreach ($checklist->getGroups() as $group) {
        $originalGroups->add($group);

        /** @var ChecklistTask $task */
        foreach ($group->getTasks() as $task) {
            $originalTasks->add($task);

            foreach ($task->getCorrectives() as $corrective) {
                $originalCorrectives->add($corrective);
            }


        }
    }


    $newTasks = new ArrayCollection();
    $newCorrectives = new ArrayCollection();

    $editForm = $this->createForm(ChecklistType::class, $checklist);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        foreach ($originalGroups as $group) {
            //$checklistgroup = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ChecklistGroup')->find($group->getId());

            if (false === $checklist->getGroups()->contains($group)) {
                $checklistgroup = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ChecklistGroup')->find($group->getId());
                $em->remove($checklistgroup);
            }
        }

        /** @var ChecklistGroup $newGroup */
        foreach ($checklist->getGroups() as $newGroup) {

            /** @var ChecklistTask $task */
            foreach ($newGroup->getTasks() as $task) {
                $newTasks->add($task);

                /* if(false === $originalTasks->contains($task)) {
                     $checklisttask = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ChecklistTask')->find($task->getId());
                     $em->remove($checklisttask);
                 }*/
            }
        }

        foreach ($originalTasks as $originalTask) {
            if (false === $newTasks->contains($originalTask)) {
                $checklisttask = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ChecklistTask')->find($originalTask->getId());
                $em->remove($checklisttask);
            }
        }

        /** @var ChecklistTask $newTask */
        foreach ($checklist->getGroups() as $newGroup) {
            /** @var ChecklistTask $task */
            foreach ($newGroup->getTasks() as $task) {
                foreach ($task->getCorrectives() as $lcorrective) {
                    $newCorrectives->add($lcorrective);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($originalCorrectives as $originalCorrective) {
            if (false === $newCorrectives->contains($originalCorrective)) {
                $checklistcorrective = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ChecklistTaskCorrective')->find($originalCorrective->getId());
                $em->remove($checklistcorrective);
            }
        }

        $checklist->setUserModificator($user);

        if ($editForm->get('Save')->isClicked()) {
            $em->persist($checklist);
            $em->flush();
        }

        if ($editForm->get('SaveCopy')->isClicked()) {
            $copy = clone $checklist;

            $copy->setNombre($checklist->getNombre(). ' #COPY#');


            $em->persist($copy);
            $em->refresh($checklist);
            $em->flush();
        }


        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Se ha actualizado el Checklist correctamente.");

        return $this->redirectToRoute('listChecklist', array('id' => $id));
    }

    return $this->render(':checklist:create.html.twig', array(
        'edit' => true,
        'form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Even after I detached it and explicitly call flush($copy).

To handle the deep copy I have the next codes:

**Checklist**

```
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->setId(null);

        $groupsClone = new ArrayCollection();

        /** @var ChecklistGroup $group */
        foreach ($this->groups as $group) {
            $itemClone = clone $group;
            $itemClone->setChecklist($this);
            $groupsClone->add($itemClone);
        }
        $this->groups = $groupsClone;
    }
}
```

**ChecklistGroup**

```
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->id = null;

        // cloning the relation M which is a OneToMany
        $tasksClone = new ArrayCollection();

        /** @var ChecklistTask $task */
        foreach ($this->getTasks() as $task) {
            $itemClone = clone $task;
            $itemClone->setChecklistgroup($this);
            $tasksClone->add($itemClone);
        }
        $this->tasks = $tasksClone;
    }
}
```

**ChecklistTask**

```
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->id = null;

        // cloning the relation M which is a OneToMany
        $correctivesClone = new ArrayCollection();

        /** @var ChecklistTaskCorrective $corrective */
        foreach ($this->getCorrectives() as $corrective) {
            $itemClone = clone $corrective;
            $itemClone->setChecklistTask($this);
            $correctivesClone->add($itemClone);
        }
        $this->correctives = $correctivesClone;
    }
}
```

**ChecklistCorrective**

```
public function __clone()
{
    if($this->id) {
        $this->setId(null);
    }
}
```

The result is both the copy and the original checklist are stored with all changes, for example if I add one group and two tasks, I get two Checklists entities with their groups and task in both of them.

Also in all my relations I've persist={"cascade"}, I don't know if that may be a problem.

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

This is what I get after testing each entity state:

```
GROUP 001 MANAGED 
TASK 001 MANAGED 
Accion Correctora 1 MANAGED 
TASK 002 MANAGED 
TASK 003 MANAGED 
GROUP 002 MANAGED 
TASK 001 MANAGED 
Accion Correctora Test MANAGED 
TASK 002 MANAGED 
GROUP 003 MANAGED 
TASK 001 MANAGED 
TASK 002 MANAGED 
TASK 003 MANAGED 
xzcxzc NEW 
xzcxzc NEW 
xzcxzc NEW
```

Existing entities of Groups, Tasks and Correctives appear like managed, added ones appear like new, $old_checklist appear like DETACHED and $copy appear like MANAGED.

Comment: will not solve your problem but you should overwrite ChecklistCorrective anyway to set the id to null when you clone it.

Comment: check in your unit of work whether your persist cascading works as expected

Comment: @LBA Tried doing a dump of $em->getUnitOfWork() just before my flush, but I don't know where to look at. In what key should I focus my attention?

Comment: have a look at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entity-state to see in which state every entity is you might be interested in

Comment: @LBA Updated with UnitOfWork results, $copy should be managed or new? Maybe there is the problem

Comment: Call $em->refresh($originalEntity) before flushing to reset it back to it's original state.

Comment: $copy should be NEW (so basically you expect a NEW entity for each and every cloned entity in your UnitOfWork)

Comment: @Cerad didn't work. I've been testing and if I create only a new group without nested tasks nor correctives it seem to work. The problem happens too if I try to remove a whole group with nested tasks.

Comment: Hmmm.  This is probably a good time to take a break and really think about what you are trying to do and maybe start fresh.  I'm guessing you have been chasing your tail a bit.  I can guarantee you the refresh will reset an entity to it's original state.  You have other stuff going on.

Comment: @Cerad I added the whole code of my EditAction function, maybe the problem is before the cloning. Is there a way to dump all entities that are being persisted? Maybe I'm missing an Entity that is persisting because of the cascade property. But I'm struggling to detect it.

Comment: All I can say is that I think you are making this more complicated than it has to be.  I don't see the reason for making all the original variables.  Maybe you need them but maybe not.  I'd focus on getting the update working then add in the clone.  All you should really need is to clone then refresh the original.

Comment: @Cerad The updating (save and overwrite) is working, I use original variables to handle Add/Remove in form through prototyping, I store the previous values, then the after submit values and then compare both to add or remove, maybe it's not the best way, I did it following a tutorial.